# Mismatch in the results between Openmodelica simulation and FMPy simulation

Tags: python, simulation, openmodelica, fmi

I have exported a model as fmu for model exchange and I have imported it in a platform for co-simulation. Although the simulation finishes fine, I do not get the expected result as the one coming from the OM simulation.

The version of OM that I use is 1.16 and I have exported the FMU though OMEdit. I am using windows and the model comes from the Photovoltaics_TGM library. For the simulation though OM the length is 1 day, namely 86400 seconds with 1440 intervals. For the simulation though python the length is again 1 day, namely 1440 mins.

Could anyone provide an insight?

I am attaching the two results.

[OM Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTpwm.png)

[FMpy Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YONWz.png)

Comment: It is impossible to provide any insight based on your report. The plots show different time frame and even different signals from what I can see. Can you provide the model?

Comment: Please add to your report: 1. what OpenModelica version did you used for the FMU export? 2. What OS do you have? 3. For the model, did you used a library shipped with OpenModelica or you downloaded one from the web? 4. what step size did you used for the FMU simulation? As far as I can see from your image the library is: https://github.com/christiankral/PhotoVoltaics/tree/master/PhotoVoltaics_TGM, is this the case?

Comment: @AdrianPop I have updated my post accordignly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not simulating the same time interval. See your x axis. For OM simulation you simulate until 100000 and for FMPy you're simulating until 1400. The curves seems to match, as you can see the OM starts below zero, then it goes to zero, then above zero, but for FMPy you don't simulate enough to get to 20000 where it starts to rise.

[image]
[image]